# Run Jquery Function for each table on page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function

I have multiple tables that are generated from a loop in wp and have written jquery to remove columns with empty td's, which works for the first table and then adds the same columns on all other tables. I have tried using 'each' with jquery to run for each table, but it doesn't.

Example:

Each table has 1 row and has the same amount of columns (7). Empty columns are hidden this works with single table. Lets say table 1 has 2 visible columns and table 2 has 3 visible columns.. the 3rd column (from table 2) gets added to table 1 even though it is empty.

Here is my jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.man-table').each(function (table) {
        //count # of columns
        var numCols = $("th", table).length;
        for ( var i=1; i<=numCols; i++ ) {
            var empty = true;
            //grab all the <td>'s of the column at i
            $("td:nth-child(" + i + ")", table).each(function(index, el) {
                //check if the <span> of this <td> is empty
                if ( $("span", el).text() != "" ) {
                    empty = false;
                    return false; //break out of each() early
                }
            });
            if ( empty ) {
                $("td:nth-child(" + i + ")", table).hide(); //hide <td>'s
                $("th:nth-child(" + i + ")", table).hide(); //hide header <th>
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Here is my table generated in for each loop

```
        <table class='man-table'>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='numeric'><span>inductance (r)</span></th>
            <th class='numeric'><span>mount</span></th>
            <th class='numeric'><span>dim (mm)</span></th>
            <th class='numeric'><span>r current</span></th>
            <th class='numeric'><span>impedance</span></th>
            <th class='numeric'><span>capacitance</span></th>
            <th class='numeric'><span>resistance</span></th>
            <th class='numeric'><span>spec</span></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td data-title='inductance (r)' class='numeric'><span>{$ind}</span></td>
            <td data-title='mount type' class='numeric'><span>{$mnt}</span></td>
            <td data-title='dimensions' class='numeric'><span>{$dim}</span></td>
            <td data-title='rated current' class='numeric'><span>{$rat}</span></td>
            <td data-title='impedance' class='numeric'><span>{$imp}</span></td>
            <td data-title='capacitance' class='numeric'><span>{$cap}</span></td>
            <td data-title='resistance' class='numeric'><span>{$res}</span></td>
            <td data-title='spec sheet' class='numeric'><span><a href='{$site_url}/product-spec/{$prod_pdf}' target='_blank;'><div id='spec-btn'>DOWNLOAD</div></a></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The issue is not clear. In your example, you suggest Table-1 has 2 columns, yet Table-2 has 3 columns. In this case, you'd want to hide the 3rd column? What do you want to happen if Table-1 has 5 columns and Table-2 only has 2 columns?

Comment: Also if you want to hide columns, you might want to add them into the `class` for more easy selection. EG: `class="col-1 numeric"` Then if you determine you need to hide a column, you can `$(".col-3", table).hide();` with ease.

Comment: @Twisty each table should hide empty columns. They should be independent of one another. Like I said.. It works fine hiding empty columns on one table... but if there is multiple tables on page, it adds the columns for the table with most columns to all tables.. Does that make sense?

Comment: How do you know when a column is empty? If one cell in one row is not empty in a table but all others in that column are empty, should it be hidden?

Comment: @Twisty there is only 1 row per table. So if any cell is empty, the column should be hidden. I edited my text above...

Comment: @Twisty cells are populated via variable.

Comment: It sounds like WP is generating the tables, so I will assume you cannot add `col-1` class to the cells. Updating answer.

Comment: @Twisty Yes, WP is generating the tables

Comment: @Twisty That was it! It is now working as expected! I guess I was over thinking it. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example that can handle a number of tables and will identify a "empty" column. This assumes the table has only 1 row.

```js
$(function() {

  function findEmptyCol(t) {
    var cols = [];
    $("tbody td", t).each(function(i, c) {
      if ($(c).text().trim() == "") {
        cols.push($(c).index());
      }
    });
    return cols;
  }

  function hideEmptyCol(tables) {
    tables.each(function(i, t) {
      var e = findEmptyCol(t);
      if (e.length) {
        $.each(e, function(k, v) {
          $("th", t).eq(v).hide();
          $("td", t).eq(v).hide();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  hideEmptyCol($(".man-table"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Table 1</h3>
<table class='man-table' id="table-1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 1</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 2</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 3</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 4</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 5</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 6</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 7</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='numeric'><span>1</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>2</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>3</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>4</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>5</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>6</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>7</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h3>Table 2</h3>
<table class='man-table' id="table-2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 1</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 2</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 3</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 4</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 5</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 6</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 7</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='numeric'><span>1</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span></span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>3</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>4</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span> </span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>6</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>7</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h3>Table 3</h3>
<table class='man-table' id="table-3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 1</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 2</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 3</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 4</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 5</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 6</span></th>
      <th class='numeric'><span>Col 7</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='numeric'><span>1</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>2</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>3</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>4</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>5</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
      <td class='numeric'><span>7</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That was it! It is now working as expected! I guess I was over thinking it. Much appreciated!

Comment: @jasone great! I hope you will mark it as the answer and upvote it.